# PySpark external table created from CSV file in ADLS shows only one column, but works with Parquet files

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am creating an external table in PySpark from a CSV file stored in ADLS. However, when I try to query the table using SQL, I am only seeing one column named "col".

Here is the PySpark code I am using to create the external table:

```
spark.sql(f"""
            CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_name>
            (
                column_1 string,
                column_2 int,
                column_3 string
            )
            USING CSV
            OPTIONS 
            (
                'delimiter'=',',
                'header'='true',
                'inferSchema'='false'
            )
            LOCATION '<abfss_location>'
        """)
```

I have verified that the CSV file has the correct number of columns and types. However, when I try to query the external table, it only shows one column named "col". Strangely enough, when I use the same code to create an external table from a Parquet file in the same location, it works perfectly fine.

Is there anything I am missing in my PySpark code that is causing the issue with the CSV file? Why does the same code work with Parquet files but not with CSV files?

Comment: Did you try reading the CSV file within a dataframe?

Comment: same code is working fine for me. re you getting any error? please share that.

Comment: Yes, I am able to read the csv file into a dataframe directly from the ADLS within a notebook and can see the tables as expected. I am even able to read it into a notebook from the lake db getting all the data as expected despite the table in the GUI only showing one column under columns. 

I do not get an error when I run the code, the table is created in the specified lake db however under columns it shows only the first column calling it "col (array<string>)". This issue carries over when attempting to query the table with SQL or in powerBI.